# Powerpoint VBA - prevent shape text from being edited

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code which creates a `RoundedRectangle` with the text **"Placeholder"**:

```
Public Sub CreateShape(currentSlide As Long, boxName As String)

    Dim oShape As Shape
    Set oShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(currentSlide).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 640, 465, 71, 27)

    With oShape
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Name = boxName

        With .TextFrame.TextRange
          .Text = "Placeholder"

        End With   ' TextFrame

    End With ' RoundedRectangle

End Sub
```

I would like to **lock the text** of this shape i.e. make a front-end user **unable to edit it**.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not easily done in VBA, you would have to add classes to unzip, edit and rezip the underlying XML. Here's my article on locking shapes by manually editing the XML: [OOXML Hacking: Locking Graphics](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/09/xml-hacking-locking-graphics/). You would want to add the **NoTextEdit="1"** attribute mentioned in the *Locking Graphics: Other Objects* section. Here's what unmodified text box XML looks like:

```
<p:sp>
    <p:nvSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="4" name="TextBox 3">
            <a:extLst>
                <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                    <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{F9D1A779-1CA7-4FA6-AFA2-B0954FC9EA09}"/>
                </a:ext>
            </a:extLst>
        </p:cNvPr>
        <p:cNvSpPr txBox="1"/>
        <p:nvPr/>
    </p:nvSpPr>
</p:sp>
```

Modified with text box lock:

```
<p:sp>
    <p:nvSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="4" name="TextBox 3">
            <a:extLst>
                <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                    <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{F9D1A779-1CA7-4FA6-AFA2-B0954FC9EA09}"/>
                </a:ext>
            </a:extLst>
        </p:cNvPr>
        <p:cNvSpPr txBox="1">
            <a:splocks noTextEdit="1"
        </p:cNvSpPr>
        <p:nvPr/>
    </p:nvSpPr>
</p:sp>
```

It's easier to do in Visual Studio using VB with the Open XML SDK. Here's some generic code for that situation:

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Namespace GeneratedCode
    Public Class GeneratedClass
        Public Function GenerateShapeLocks() As ShapeLocks
            Dim shapeLocks1 As ShapeLocks = New ShapeLocks() With {
                .NoTextEdit = True
            }
            Return shapeLocks1
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: This is going to take me a while to wrap my head around (no fault of yours), especially cuz I've never used Visual Studio to modify PPT files - I promise I'll mark it as the accepted answer once I do; I just can't verify that it works immediately.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of how I'd unzip, edit, and rezip the underlying XML in VBA? I've read through your article, but the issue is that I'm trying to lock a shape that hasn't yet been created.

Comment: With VBA, I use a class that was written by Jan Karel Pieterse: https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007FileFormat02.asp. He wrote this for Excel, but for a small fee, he'll write a PowerPoint version. The workflow is to get everything possible done in PowerPoint with VBA (like creating your shape), then save and close the file, unzip it with the class module, do find and replace operations to change the VBA, then rezip the file back to PowerPoint format.